# Number of distinct roots of an irreducible polynomial divides the degree of the polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $f(X)$ be an irreducible polynomial in the polynomial ring $k[X]$ over the field $k$. Prove that the number of distinct roots of $f(X)$ divides the degree of $f(X)$.

Comment: If f has a root isn't it either linear or reducible?

Comment: @Gaffney No. Consider $X^2+2$ over $\mathbb R$. (The roots don't have to be in $k$.)

Comment: Strictly speaking Gaffney is correct. The question should refer to roots in a splitting field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Irreducible polynomials over fields of characteristic zero have distinct roots (in the splitting field), so it suffices to consider the case where $k$ has positive characteristic. Fix some $f$ over such a $k$. We may assume $f$ has repeated roots, or the result is trivial.

The multiple roots are roots of $\gcd(f,f')$. Since $f$ is irreducible, it must divide $f'$, and this is only possible if $f'=0$, so $f(X)=g(X^p)$, where $p$ is the characteristic of $k$. We may continue this process to write $f(X)=h(X^{{p^e}})$, where $e\ge1$ and $h$ is irreducible and separable. Hence every root of $f$ has the same multiplicity $p^e$, and the result follows.

Comment: I don't understand "continue this process." Could you please explain?

Comment: I agree with @Myath that perhaps "continue the process" could need further explanation. Alternatively, Gallian, 6th edition, theorem 20.9 contains another argument to see this.

Comment: @Potato can we argue like this :since the field is of characteristic $p$ hence$ f(x^p) =(f(x)) ^p$ hence if $x$ is a root then so is $x^p$. Now since p is prime hence $x^p$ is a generator of $\Bbb{Z} _p$. Hence there will be p distinct roots.@Rodrigo